# Mean coordinates in QGIS yields displaced point from centroid

Tags: qgis, coordinates, mean

I need to get the weighted centroid from a grid layer (according to an attribute of the polygons on this layer). For that, I am using the "mean coordinates" tool, but I realized that the yielded points are displaced from the place they should be located. This is clear when I apply a mean coordinate to just one feature, like in the image:

[image: Feature with centroid (orange) and point yielded by mean coordinates tool (red)]

The red point is the one yielded by the mean coordinates, while the orange one appears to be the logic centroid for the selected feature (yellow piece from grid). Distance between both points is around 20m, but this distance it's not always the same for other cases (even though it's around that value).

Can this be due to having a different CRS for the grid from the project one?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what did you set as the weight?

Comment: Yes, CRS might be the reason. Use same CRS for layer and project

Comment: *"Can this be due to having a different CRS for the grid from the project one?"* - this is easy to test and you may answer your own question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can this be due to having a different CRS for the grid from the project one?

I don't think so. This is more likely caused by that the polygon starts and ends in the lower left corner. (that means there are two points there), or there are other points (vertex) there. A polygon having `n` vertices has `n+1` points in QGIS.

You can test it by creating polygons starting from different corner:

[image]

Comment: Makes sense, didn't know that. Therefore, in order to obtain the weighted centroids, I first get centroids for each grid feature, then obtaining the mean coordinates from those centroids. Just tested, the result is good. Thank you so much!